# Zen Code to create html layout for a sudoku solver

Tags: html, css, emmet

I'm making a sudoku solver in html/css/js
the layout i'm going for is:
a main container div
    
    
             .
             .
             .
    
end main container div

I've gotten this far in zen code
div#container>input:text*81
but if I try to add an id it doesn't work
    div#container>input:text*81#i$

Comment: try replacing `input:text` with `input[type="text"]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
div#container>input:text#$*81
```